# What is the difference between Session::set and Session::put in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

What is the difference between the `Session::set` and `Session::put` methods in Laravel? The docs only covers `Session::put`, but I have seen `set` used instead.

Answer (score 10):

They are exactly the same. `Session::put` directly calls `Session::set`.

The only difference, is that `Session::put` allows you to pass it an array of `[key => value]` pairs, in which case it calls `Session::set` for each of them.

These methods are defined in [`Illuminate\Session\Store`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/132febfd9e9cbb954b532c7b601fae45a7523765/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php#L377)

Comment: `Session::set` has been removed in Laravel 5.4, so `Session::put` should be used.